# Getting access to VM's console with Python

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script that creates and runs several VMs via **virsh** for the user.   Some of the configuration has to be done by executing commands inside the VM which I would want to do automatically.

What would be the easiest way to get remote shell access in Python?   I am considering the following approaches:

1. To use the **virsh console** command as a sub-process and do I/O to it.
2. To bring up an SSH session to the VM.   I can configure the VM before it boots by editing its file system so I know its target IP address.
3. Any better API for doing this.  RPC?

I need to get the return values for commands so I know if they executed correctly or not.   For that matter I need to be able to detect when a program I invoke has finished.   Options #1 and #2 rely on scraping the output and that gets complex.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: if you can configure the IP in advance, can you put a shell script to do the configuration on it and invoke that over ssh?

Comment: @Eric I was thinking along those lines but that is my last option.   Such a script could just be started as an upstart job and do everything; the problem is that if anything goes wrong with it the program I have interacting with the user will have a hard time detecting it.

Comment: if you use qemu - you need to create a console socket using --monitor option. Or: $ virsh qemu-monitor-command devstack \
--pretty '{"execute":"query-kvm"}'